# How can I check the status of a Windows scheduled task using python?

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, status

I need to check the status of a Windows scheduled task using python, verifying it by the name of the task.
I basically want to know if the task is running or not.

I've searched for an answer but I didn't find any.

How can I do that?

**Edit:**
Based on the comments below, the best way to achieve this AND to have the result in some kind of variable (checking if the State is 'Running', for instance) is this:

```
"Running" in check_output(["C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe", '-Command', '&{Get-ScheduledTask -TaskPath \* | where taskname -eq "TaskName" | select state;}'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the subprocess module.

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(r'schtasks.exe /query  /tn "TASKNAME_HERE"', shell=True)
```

If you get access denied, may need to change string to pass server address and credentials like so:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(r'schtasks.exe /query /S 192.168.1.100 /u domain\username /P pass /tn "TASKNAME_HERE"', shell=True)
```

As discussed below, to get only the "state" of the command, it is easy to use powershell. Try this:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(["C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe", '-Command', '&{Get-ScheduledTask -TaskPath \* | where taskname -eq "Ajustar Inventario SM" | select state;}'])
```

This will return:

```
State
-----
Ready
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! However, I still have two problems:
1.My task is under a folder <folder_name> inside Task Scheduler. So, when I simply use the first command you wrote (or even the second one), it is not able to find it. I think I have to specify in some way this folder in the command. Do you know how to do that?
2. When I run the first command on a task placed on the root, I get access denied. I tried your 2nd command and I've got this: "ERROR: User credentials are not allowed on the local machine." I am running the command to try to find out the task status in the local machine.

Comment: I do not know why it is denied, but, to get to a folder it is `/TN \Microsoft\Windows\Taskname` or wherever your task is

Comment: Yes, I could resolve the folder issue. Thank you!
is there a way to get only the Status attribute? I have to parse its value.

Here is the actual output:
`
Folder: sm-scripts
TaskName                                 Next Run Time          Status
======================================== ====================== =============== <br/>
Ajustar Inventario SM                    13/04/2020 18:30:00    Ready`

Comment: I've made an edit, should be fine to paste as-is, no credentials needed.

Comment: Thank you! I've made and edit in my original post. It worked well. I changed your solution to use check_output, since I needed to parse the output of the command and the function subprocess.call does not allow it, as I've searched.